# Height percentage + static height of image

Tags: flash, static, height

I created a swf file not long ago, and I have some meaningless 'broken' link to a once existing affiliate. I wanted to take this link off of my game, but it appears as though I lost my .fla file. =/

So what I want to do is JUST display my main game content at 100%, so the broken link is not being displayed. The ad for the affiliate is a static 100px.

So basically what I would want to do is set the height to 100% + 100px, so the link is out of view unless you scroll down. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i get it right.

1. you can embed your swf and set the
   size which you need to a new swf
   file.
2. you can play with html and css to
   hide content which you don't want to
   show.

**Update:**
i will try to explaine my idea about first method more clear.

1. create a new flash movie in a flash.
2. set stage width and height to the 
      width = old_SWF_file.width;
      height = old_SWF_file.width - bunner.height; //-100px
3. import old swf file to the stage to the point(0,0), so  the banner should be out from the stage, and shouldn be visible for user.

`

Comment: Right. But I want the main content to show @ fullscreen for all of my users. However, based on screen resolution and browser variety, I need to set the 'fullscreen' to a percentage. However, I also need to add 100px to the 100% of the height.

Comment: in this case i see only the embeding you swf into a new swf. I´m not sure is this possible but you can try to make a new swf 100px smaller in height than your current swf.

Comment: You cannot edit .swf in Flash sadly. =[

Maybe there is some type of javascript that can get the static height of the browser area, and add 100px? =o